# Issue binding API Gateway to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a simple ApiGateway on top of a DynamoDB to add a endpoint for users to access the data trough this.

Integration type **AWS Service**

AWS Region **eu-west-1**

AWS Service **DynamoDB**

AWS Subdomain

HTTP method **GET**

Action **ListResources**

Execution role **[iam arn]**

Credentials cache **Do not add caller credentials to cache key**

Content Handling **Passthrough**

When I click the test Button i get :

Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role

Checked here and there but have no clue on the problem. I tried changing the permissions of the IAM user and gave him all Dynamo and APIGateway rights, but no change.

Comment: This tutorial matches your requirements well, and starts off in high detail on IAM:  https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is linked to the fact that I used a IAM user instead of an IAM Role. I'll leave that here, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

First, update the execution role to use a role rather than an IAM user.  Then, ensure that the role has permissions for all of the DynamoDB operations and resources that you want to access.  Finally, grant API Gateway permissions to assume that role by adding an IAM trust policy as shown below.

From section "API Gateway Permissions Model for Invoking an API"  [on documentation page here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html)

> When an API is integrated with an AWS service (for example, AWS Lambda) in the back end, API Gateway must also have permissions to access integrated AWS resources (for example, invoking a Lambda function) on behalf of the API caller. To grant these permissions, create an IAM role of the Amazon API Gateway type. This role contains the following IAM trust policy that declares API Gateway as a trusted entity that is permitted to assume the role:

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}`